boolean modifier round edge edge


when i try to use the boolean modifier i am getting this weird edge, but i need  sharp edge, i don't know why this is happening
i tried extruding the face along normal , but still it have the artifact



hello, what is the final goal? Static character? Animated character? You don't need a boolean for this shape, just extrude some edges inwards

Do you have any other modifiers on this mesh?

I have Mirror and subdivision modifier, @TheLabCat

@moonboots Why the Boolean is not working, I have Mirror and subdivision modifier on the object.

Please share your file

The Boolean modifier is working, but because of one or more of several things, possibly including what order the modifiers are in, you’re not getting what you want in terms of normals.

@moonboots i tried extruding theface along the normals but  still it have the artifact

Please share your file, your topology doesn't seem optimal

https://we.tl/t-PaHYmb3FCR  ,@moonboots

You should use a more traditional topology, mostly quads, no Mark Sharp, bevel the edge that you want to keep sharp

@moonboots i changed the topology now its working , thanks
